# Extracting amplitude information from sum of two step functions

Tags: regression, time-series, modeling, fourier-transform

Background:

I'm looking at power information from a circuit powering multiple freezers, resulting in a signal that is the sum of two step functions, with slightly different frequencies. I'm looking to extend this to cases with four freezers on one circuit, so am trying to automate the analysis.

[image: The signals from the freezers]

Problem:

I want to work out the amplitudes of the individual steps making up the total signal so I can see if particular freezers draw more power than others.

I've tried getting a power spectrum from the data, which looks like this:

[image: The power spectrum]

But to be honest I'm not too sure if this helps at all. I'm not too sure how to proceed from here, or if Fourier Transforms are a good idea at all. I'm generally new to time-series analysis.

I've had a look at this question, but I'm not sure it exactly answers how to find the actual amplitudes of the steps:
[Decompose a time series into superposition of step functions?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/130367/decompose-a-time-series-into-superposition-of-step-functions)